# Show page not found in Angular2

Tags: angular, routes

I am using the new routing (3.0.0-alpha.3), and would like to show a nice "page not found" for any user navigating to a route that does not exists. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: The latest one is actually Angular Router 3.0.0-alpha.7 https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9345

Comment: Can you point out a solution to the problem using alpha.7?

Comment: I think there is a `NavigationError` event you could handle

Comment: @AngJobs There was indeed a NavigationError i used this in the router event to solve my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As AngJobs commented there is indeed a NavigationError. I used the router event observable to subscribe for router events, and see if one is a NavigationError:

```
constructor(private _router: Router) {
    this._router.events.subscribe((event: NavigationError) => {
      if (event.error) {
        this._router.navigate(['/error']);
      }
    });
  }
```